# I don't know why my page isn't paginating i don't get any errors pls help :)

Tags: django, django-views

The page is supposed to get paginated but it doesn't I don't know what I did wrong. If anyone can help me figure it out i will appreciate

This is for a comment section on a site and I don't really know how to fix it. I've been looking the problem up on the web with no results then came here

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def Home_view(request):

    posts = Post.objects.order_by("-date_posted")
    all_experiences = Experience.objects.order_by("-id")
    all_educations = Education.objects.order_by("-id")
    all_skills = Skill.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 1)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    post_list = paginator.get_page(page)

    context = {

        'posts': posts,

        'all_experiences': all_experiences,

        'all_educations': all_educations,

        'all_skills': all_skills,

    }
    return render(request, 'resume.html', context)
```

Html Page supposed to get paginated

```
{% if is_paginated %}
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if post_list.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
        <a href="?page={{ post_list.previous_page_number }}">previous
        </a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
           Page{{post_list.number}}of{{post_list.paginator.num_pages}}.
        </span>

        {% if post_list.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ post_list.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        <a href="?page={{ post_list.paginator.num_pages }}">last&raquo;
        </a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% else %}
```

the page is supposed to show 5 posts at once but doesn't and doesn't throw out any errors it just doesn't work

Comment: You should add `post_list` to the render context. And `is_paginated` is also missing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't adding `post_list` to your context so `{% if post_list.has_previous %}` does nothing. You are passing `posts` which is the unpaginated list of posts. You will also need to add `is_paginated` to the context. Try updating `context` to something like:

```
context = {

        'all_experiences': all_experiences,

        'all_educations': all_educations,

        'all_skills': all_skills,

        'post_list': post_list,

        'is_paginated': True,

    }
```

Comment: Thank your answer helped me but the html still displays the incorrect amount of post but the logic of the paginator works fine displaying the correct amount of pages but with the wrong amount of post's